# Filter matrix using subvector row

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of the form:

```
m = 1, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50;
    2, 1, 11, 20, 30, 40, 50;
    3, 0, 12, 20, 30, 40, 50;
    4, 1, 12, 21, 30, 40, 50;
```

For a given column index (say 3) and row index (say 1), I'd like to filter out all rows that have the same values to the right of that column in that row. Using the above example of m, columnIndex = 3, and rowIndex = 1 (noted with asterisks):

```
                  **
f(m, 3) = * 1, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50;    % [20, 30, 40, 50] matches itself, include
            2, 1, 11, 20, 30, 40, 50;    % [20, 30, 40, 50] matches the subvector in row 1, include
            3, 0, 12, 20, 30, 40, 50;    % [20, 30, 40, 50] matches the subvector in row 1, include
            4, 1, 12, 21, 30, 40, 50;    % [21, 30, 40, 50] does NOT match the subvector in row 1, filter this out
```

How can I achieve this behavior? I've tried this, but I'm getting an dimension mismatch error.

```
key = data( rowIndex, columnIndex:end );
filteredData = ( data( :, columnIndex:end ) == key );
```

Comment: I should mention that I'm used to coding, but I'm relatively new to Matlab and don't know what I would call this sort of task. A form of logical indexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index those that you keep with `==` within `bsxfun()`:

```
r = 3;
c = 2;

idx = all(bsxfun(@eq, m(:,c:end),m(r,c:end)),2);
m(idx,:)
```

Comment: Technically, `isequal` is not the same thing as the built-in `eq`.

Comment: @EitanT Thanks, amended answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to use the `isequal` operator, documented [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html).

```
isequal(m(1,columnIndex:end),key)
```

and here's kind of an inefficient one liner :-)

```
cellfun(@(x) isequal(key,x),mat2cell(m(:,columnIndex:end),ones(1,size(m,2)-columnIndex+1)))
```

Here's how it goes

1. Change the matrix to a cell array of the subvectors we're interested in: `mat2cell(m(:,columnIndex:end),ones(1,size(m,2)-columnIndex+1))`
2. Anonymous function to run on each cell element: `@(x) isequal(key,x)`
3. Function to cause each cell element to be passed to the anonymous function, `cellfun`

My answer using `m` above as an example:

```
cellfun(@(x) isequal(key,x),mat2cell(m(:,columnIndex:end),ones(1,size(m,2)-columnIndex+1)))

ans =

     1
     1
     1
     0
```

HTH!